# Need the settings of SQL developer "F5"

Tags: settings, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need the settings in `SQL Developer` while performing the action `Run as Script` -[f5](/questions/tagged/f5).
Since, if I use `sqlplus`. it is not giving the exact result format what I want. But, in `SQL Developer` gives the needed format. I tried in all kind of settings, its not giving the same as `SQL Developer` prints...

So, settings like,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000 FORMAT WRAPPED;
SET LONG 5000;
SET LIN 4000;
SET PAGESIZE 5000;
```

I need this kind of settings, for output display settings.
Anyone can help on this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-answer, but try posting in the official OTN Sql Developer forums. The devs are very active about fielding questions posted there.